# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element

Tags: xml, parsing

I am getting this error when I try to view my dynamically generated (PHP) XML document:

XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://dev.leisurepublishing.com/vtc/master.xml.php
Line Number 17, Column 1:
^

I have googled and looked through the document and I can't figure out what's wrong, can someone help me spot the problem?

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/xml");
require_once("admin/assets/db_connect.php");

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
?>

<master> 

<categories>
    <category>
        <gsm>GFoo</gsm>
        <category_id>1</category_id>
    </category>
    <category>
        <gsm>SFoo</gsm>
        <category_id>2</category_id>
    </category>
    <category>
        <gsm>MFoo</gsm>
        <category_id>3</category_id>
    </category>
</categories>

<region_codes>
    <code>
        <code_id>11000</code_id>
        <code_name>Central</code_name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <code_id>12000</code_id>
        <code_name>Eastern</code_name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <code_id>13000</code_id>
        <code_name>Western</code_name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <code_id>14000</code_id>
        <code_name>Northern</code_name>
    </code>
</region_codes>

<headers>
    <header>
        <header_id>1</header_id>
        <header_name>Featured A</header_name>
    </header>
    <header>
        <header_id>2</header_id>
        <header_name>Featured B</header_name>
    </header>
    <header>
        <header_id>3</header_id>
        <header_name>Featured C</header_name>
    </header>
</headers>

<advertisers>
    <partner>
        <name>Crestline</name>
        <file>crestline.asp</file>
        <logo>microsites/crestline/logo.jpg</logo>
        <blurb>blah blah blah.</blurb>
        <cat>3</cat>
        <region>15000</region>
        <header_type>1</header_type>
    </partner>
    <partner>
        <name>Example 2</name>
        <file>example2.asp</file>
        <logo>microsites/meeting/example2.jpg</logo>
        <blurb>example 2 example 2 example 2 example 2 example 2 example 2 example 2 example 2 example 2 .</blurb>
        <cat>2</cat>
        <region>14000</region>
        <header_type>1</header_type>
    </partner>
    <partner>
        <name>Example 3</name>
        <file>example3.asp</file>
        <logo>microsites/meeting/example3.jpg</logo>
        <blurb>example 3 example 3 example 3 example 3 example 3 example 3 .</blurb>
        <cat>3</cat>
        <region>11000</region>
        <header_type>1</header_type>
    </partner>
  <partner>
    <name>Example 4</name>
    <file>example4.asp</file>
    <logo>microsites/meeting/example4.jpg</logo>
    <blurb>example 4 example 4 example 4 example 4 example 4 example 4.</blurb>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <region>11000</region>
    <header_type>1</header_type>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <name>Example 5</name>
    <file>example5.asp</file>
    <logo>microsites/meeting/example5.jpg</logo>
    <blurb>example 5 example 5 example 5 example 5 example 5 example 5.</blurb>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <region>11000</region>
    <header_type>1</header_type>
  </partner>

  <partner>
    <name>Example 6</name>
    <file>example6.asp</file>
    <logo>microsites/meeting/example6.jpg</logo>
    <blurb>example 6 example 6 example 6 example 6 example 6 example 6.</blurb>
    <cat>2</cat>
    <region>11000</region>
    <header_type>2</header_type>
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <name>Example 7</name>
    <file>example7.asp</file>
    <logo>microsites/meeting/example7.jpg</logo>
    <blurb>example 7 example 7 example 7 example 7 example 7 example 7.</blurb>
    <cat>3</cat>
    <region>11000</region>
    <header_type>3</header_type>
  </partner>

  <partner>
    <name>Example 8</name>
    <file>example8.asp</file>
    <logo>microsites/meeting/example8.jpg</logo>
    <blurb>example 8 example 8 example 8 example 8 example 8 example 8.</blurb>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <region>11000</region>
    <header_type>3</header_type>
  </partner>

  <partner>
    <name>Example 9</name>
    <file>example9.asp</file>
    <logo>microsites/meeting/example9.jpg</logo>
    <blurb>example 9 example 9 example 9 example 9 example 9 example 9.</blurb>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <region>11000</region>
    <header_type>3</header_type>
  </partner>

  <partner>
    <name>Example 10</name>
    <file>example10.asp</file>
    <logo>microsites/meeting/example10.jpg</logo>
    <blurb>example 10 example 10 example 10 example 10 example 10 example 10.</blurb>
    <cat>1</cat>
    <region>12000</region>
    <header_type>2</header_type>
  </partner>

</advertisers>

</master>

<?php

require_once("admin/assets/db_disconnect.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all PHP header tags except `xml` and add:

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  I found that the path to the last require_once() was bad and when I fixed the path the parse error went away too.

Comment: Yes, PHP probably output an error about the bad path, that therefore appeared after closing root element, hence the 'junk' error: you're not supposed to have anything after the root element.